# Exception handling in PostgreSQL function with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

have write the following store procedure in Postgres. This SP simply accept the incoming parameters, insert it into the table and return current identity. More I have also declare an addition variable that will tell is the sp runs successfully or not.

I am new to Postgres and have not much knowledge about Postgres way to do this. I want some thing like BEGIN TRY, END TRY and BEGIN CATCH, END CATCH like we do in MSSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usp_save_message(msg_sub character varying(80), msg_content text, msg_type character(12), msg_category character(255),msg_created_by character(255),msg_updated_by character(255))
  RETURNS msg_id character, success boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    msg_id character;
    success boolean;
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY:
  set success = 0
  set msg_id = INSERT INTO tbl_messages(
            message_subject, message_content, message_type, message_category, 
            created_on, created_by, updated_on, updated_by)
    VALUES (msg_sub, msg_cont, msg_type,msg_category, LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
            msg_created_by, LOCALTIMESTAMP, msg_updated_by) RETURNING message_id;
   set success = 1
   RETURN msg_id,success;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I want something like this:

```
begin proc()
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY:
        set success = 0
        execute the query
        set success = 1
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH:
   set success = 0
  END CATCH
  set success = 1
END
```

More I have to catched both these return values in django views.

**I have updated the question and it is as now;**

Here is the table,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_messages
(
  message_subject character varying(80),
  message_content text,
  message_type character(12),
  message_category character(255),
  created_on timestamp without time zone,
  created_by character(255),
  updated_on timestamp without time zone,
  updated_by character(255),
  message_id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_messages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tbl_messages
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;
```

Here is the function i created;

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_save_message(IN msg_sub character varying, IN msg_cont text, IN msg_type character varying, IN msg_category character varying, IN msg_created_by character varying, IN msg_updated_by character varying, OUT success boolean, OUT msg_id integer) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_messages
        (message_subject, message_content, message_type, message_category, 
       created_on, created_by, updated_on, updated_by)
    VALUES 
      (msg_sub, msg_cont, msg_type, msg_category, LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
       msg_created_by, LOCALTIMESTAMP, msg_updated_by)
    returning message_id
    into msg_id;

    success := true;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN others then 
      success := false;
      msg_id := null;
  END;
  return msg_id,success;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_save_message(IN character varying, IN text, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying)
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;
```

But it is not still working... i don't know what id have done wrong now, any django/postgres expert here kindly help me out.

Comment: This entire SP is unnecessary.  IN pgsql you can simple do an INSERT ... RETURNING msg_id and handle failed inserts as normal.

Comment: No such thing as "Store Procedure". You mean "Stored Procedure", the equivalent of which is a *function* in Postgres. You need study the basics in the excellent manual first: [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) and [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your function:

1. Statements need to be terminated with a `;` - always
2. Variable assignments are done using `:=` (see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)
3. You can't return more than one value from a function (unless you create a set returning function, return an object or use `out` parameters)
4. Boolean values are `true` or `false`. Not `0` or `1` (those are numbers)
5. The result of an automatically generated ID value is better obtained using `lastval()` or `` INSERT ... RETURNING expressions INTO ...`not through a`SET` statement.

Exception handling is done using the `exception` clause [as documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

So you need something like this:

```
DECLARE
....

BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_messages
        (message_subject, message_content, message_type, message_category, 
       created_on, created_by, updated_on, updated_by)
    VALUES 
      (msg_sub, msg_cont, msg_type,msg_category, LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
       msg_created_by, LOCALTIMESTAMP, msg_updated_by)
    returning message_id
    into msg_id;

    success := true;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN others then 
      success := false;
      msg_id := null;
  END;
  return msg_id;
END;
```

But as I said: you can't return more than one value from a function. The only way to do this is to declare `OUT` parameters, but personally I find them a bit hard to handle in SQL clients.

You have the following options to report an error to the caller:

1. let the *caller* handle the exception/error that might arise (which is what I prefer)
2. define a new user defined data type that contains the message_id and the success flag and return that (but that means you lose the error message!)
3. return a `NULL` for the message_id to indicate that something went wrong (but that also means you lose the error information)
4. Use `out` parameters to pass both values. An example is available in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-OUTPUT-PARAMETERS

Comment: `OUT` parameters are *one* (good) way to return multiple columns. Other ways: Return a composite type (row type); return an anonymous record (requires column definition list on call); use `RETURNS TABLE` (which can return 0-n rows)

Comment: I have updated the question with your help, kindly review it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_save_message3(IN msg_sub character varying, IN msg_cont text, IN msg_type character varying, IN msg_category character varying, IN msg_created_by character varying, IN msg_updated_by character varying) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ DECLARE msg_id integer := 0;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_messages
        (message_subject, message_content, message_type, message_category, 
       created_on, created_by, updated_on, updated_by)
    VALUES 
      (msg_sub, msg_cont, msg_type, msg_category, LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
       msg_created_by, LOCALTIMESTAMP, msg_updated_by);
      Select into msg_id currval('tbl_messages_message_id_seq');
  return msg_id;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_save_message(IN character varying, IN text, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying, IN character varying)
  OWNER TO gljsxdlvpgfvui;



SELECT fn_save_message3('Test','fjaksdjflksadjflas','email','news','taqi@gmail.com','');
```